# Can you answer my question about tense usage in common English conversations?

Tags: tense-agreement

[The video st 0:39](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RBFm7-UkXMI)

In an anime, people discover that the masked evil man is none other than Obito who was supposed to be dead during the last war. A comrade of his says:

> I thought you died.

I wonder how would it be different if he had said:

> I thought you were dead.

What's the difference in usage between the two?

Comment: The noun **doubt** is **not** a synonym for **question**. **Doubt** is uncertainty, or distrust. I am curious about this: several S. Asian questioners have used _doubt_ as if it is synonymous with _question._ Is there a dictionary which gives you this meaning?

Comment: There is no difference in tense: both are simple past, the first of "to die" and the second of "to be." In normal conversation, a native English speaker would use either of your examples with no significant difference in meaning.

Comment: @P.E.Dant http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2429/can-doubt-sometimes-mean-question